# jQuery form validation using each() not working as expected

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, each

I am trying to create my own simple form validation while looping through all the form elements with the class '.required' using each().

The problem is, it keeps breaking out of the loop and always jumps to 'return true;' even if all the fields are empty.

This is the html:

```
<input type="text" id="personal-name" name="personal-name" class="required-field" placeholder="First Name">
```

And this is the jQuery code:

```
function validForm() {

    var privacyApprove = $('#privacy-approved');
    var errorWindow = $('.errors');

    // Fade out the error after 3 seconds
    var errorFadeOut = setInterval(function () {
        errorWindow.fadeOut();
        clearInterval(errorFadeOut);
    }, 3000);

    if (!privacyApprove.is(':checked')) {
        errorWindow.fadeIn().text("יש להסכים לתנאי התקנון");
        return false;
    }

    $('input.required-field, textarea.required-field').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == 0) {
                errorWindow.fadeIn().text("אנא השלם את כל הפרטים הנדרשים המודגשים באדום");
                $(this).addClass('input-error');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('input-error');
            }
    });

    return true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to do

```
if ($(this).val() == '')
```

instead of

```
if ($(this).val() == 0)
```

A valid alternative would be

```
if ($(this).val().length == 0)
```

Also, you should avoid returning `true` always. Change your return value to this

```
return $('.input-error').length == 0
```

Comment: Thanks, it would be more valid syntax, but still doesn't solve the problem, it seems like the each() is breaking out of the loop even though he found an empty field and jumps right to the 'return: true;' statement.

Comment: @Pro5per: the loop will eventually finish and execute the next instruction, in this case, `return true`. If you want to avoid this, you'll need to add some condition to return true or false depending invalid count.

Comment: thanks a lot for the updated answer, I ended up using yours in the end as it was much shorter. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If the code gets the the each block it will always return true.  You do not have any logic that will return false.

Possible add something like this after the each

```
if ($('input-error'))
  return false
else
  return true
```

Comment: It solved it!
Thanks a lot!
I used $('input, textarea').hasClass('input-error').
Thanks for the enlightenment :)

Comment: Glad to help.  Can you mark the question answered with my answer.  Thanks